# Render 1 million Markers Google Map

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-markers

I need some way to render more than 1 million markes in google Map, try to render 60,000 but it took me more than 8 seconds, because I am creating in them infoWinfow and events, if you have any recommendations please let me know.

Comment: Why would you need to render that many at the same time? Consider just displaying a subset and adjust that subset if the map view changes.

Comment: Official documentation suggests clustering: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/marker-clustering